# best algorithm for search between arrays

Tags: c#, algorithm, search

I have a problem I need to solve in the best algorithm I can find.
Let me describe the problem first.
I have a class `A` with number of `Hashset<int>` with `Z` number of items

```
A -> {x,y,z | x = {0,1,2} , y = {-1,0,9} ... }
B -> {x,y,z,k | x = {0,1,-2} , y = {-1,0,19} ... }
```

...

with an input of a new array of `int` { ... } entered by the user, the result should be the group with the most hashset with matching numbers between the input and the groups.

For example :

```
A : {[1,2,3][2,3,8][-1,-2,2]}  
B : {[0,-9,3][12,23,68][-11,-2,2]}
```

Input :

```
[2,3,-19]

result A : {[2,3][2,3][2]}  
result B : {[3][][2]}

A : 3  
B : 2
```

A is the correct answer.

Or something like that .
Yes, I know it's a subjective question but it's for a good cause.

Comment: Please, use  `{}` tool box button to represent your code parts. Right now I did this for you.

Comment: your own example seems flawed, with input [2,3,-11] shouldn't result B turn up as: {[3][][-11,2]}?

Comment: If you want to ask for `the best` you must tell us how to measure that. Do you want the simplest to understand? The fastest on average? The fastest in best-case? The fastest in worst-case? Etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have an unknown number of samples to check on the input set, this Linq query should do the trick.

```
from sample in samples
let intersectedSets =
  from set in sample
  let intersection = input.Intersect(set)
  where intersection.Count() > 0
  select intersection
orderby intersectedSets.Count() descending
select intersectedSets;
```

The top-most element is your desired sample, thus `yourCollection.First()` will yield your result set - In your given example:

```
var samples = new[] {
  new[]{
    new[]{1, 2, 3},
    new[]{2, 3, 8},
    new[]{-1, -2, 2}
  },
  new[]{
    new[]{0, -9, 3},
    new[]{12, 23, 68},
    new[]{-11, -2, 2}
  }
};
var input = new[]{2, 3, -19};

var result =
  (from sample in samples
  let intersectedSets =
    from set in sample
    let intersection = input.Intersect(set)
    where intersection.Count() > 0
    select intersection
  orderby intersectedSets.Count() descending
  select intersectedSets).First();

result.Dump(); // LINQPad extension method
```

Answer (score 0):

apparently you want to use C# to implement this. I don't know if this is the *best* algorithm (in whatever context) but you could use LINQ to write it down very plain and simple:

```
        int[][] arrays = new[] { new[] { 1, 2 }, new[] { 2, 3 }, new[] {3, 4} };
        int[] input = new[] { 1, 4 };
        Console.WriteLine(arrays.Count((itemarray) => itemarray.Any((item) => input.Contains(item))));
```

in an array of int arrays this finds the number of arrays that have at least one of the values of the input array. this is what you're doing, though I'm not sure if it's what you're asking of us.

Answer (score 0):

Given a sample class `HashHolder` and an instance `A` of it:

```
public class HashHolder
{
    public HashHolder()
    {
        Hashes = new List<HashSet<int>>();
    }
    public List<HashSet<int>> Hashes { get; set; }
}
```

You can group by hashset and take the maximum count between all groups:

```
var maxHash = A.Hashes.GroupBy(h => h)
               .Select(g => new { Hash = g.Key, Count = input.Count(num => g.Key.Contains(num)) })
               .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count)
               .FirstOrDefault();
```

The result will then be `maxHash.Hash` if `maxhHash` is not null.